# error FacebookResponseException when use SDK PHP to post a link

Tags: php, facebook, laravel-5

i'm using sdk php to post a link. here is my function (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/postwithgraphapi/)

```
 public function shareFB(Request $request, $slugify)
{
    $petition = Petitions::where('slug', $slugify)->first();
    // $access_token = auth()->user()->social_account->access_token;

    $fb = new Facebook([
      'app_id' => config("services.facebook.client_id"),
      'app_secret' => config("services.facebook.client_secret"),
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
    ]);

    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();

    $linkData = [
      'link' => route('petitions.index',$petition->slug),
      'message' => $request->get('comment-fb'),
    ];

    try {
        $response = $fb->post('/me/feed', $linkData, '$access_token');
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    $share = $response->getGraphNode();

    return redirect()->route('petitions.index',$petition->slug);
}
```

and error is Invalid OAuth access token, maybe i get wrong access token. Anyone help me solve that/ Thank u

Comment: I think the error is pretty self-explaining? Make sure to fill in the right access token in `config("services.facebook.client_secret")` which is in the `config/services.php` or the `.env` file

Comment: yeah. i had use echo 'services.facebook.client_secret' and reponse correct value.